# how to detect if code is running on android or java se?

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I have a library that will be run on either Android or Java SE.  The library has different behaviour depending on the runtime, for example:

```
boolean runningOnJavaSE = isRunningOnJavaSE();
if (runningOnJavaSE)
{
   doJavaSESetup();
} 
else 
{
   doAndroidSetup();
}
```

How can this be done?

Many thanks.

Comment: You could try checking the System.getProperty("os.name") value

Comment: Have a look at [`System.getProperty()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String))